# Как можно получить id страницы объекта в UMI CMS?

Tags: cms, php, umi

Здравствуйте.

Есть object_id. Нужно как-то получить id соответвующей страницы.

Пример:

```
<udata generation-time="0.114856">

<page id="11" parentId="0" link="/articles/novaya_stranica_kontenta/" is-active="1" object-id="27146" type-id="10" update-time="1254299905" alt-name="novaya_stranica_kontenta">
  <basetype id="2" module="content" method="">Страницы контента</basetype>
  <name>Новая страница контента</name>

  <properties>

   <group id="3183" name="svojstva_publikacii">
    <title>Свойства публикации</title>

    <property id="9029" name="publish_status" type="relation">
     <title>Авторы</title>
      <value>
       <item id="27085" name="Лавров Максим" type-id="745" ownerId="14" xlink:href="uobject://27085"/>
      </value>
    </property>

   </group>

  </properties>

 </page>
</udata>
```

Вот тут в property=9029 есть список авторов статьи, авторы представлены отдельными страницами. 
На странице статьи есть выпадающий список с авторами.

Суть проблемы:  
В шаблоне XSLT в момент обработки шаблона статьи нужно, в блоке авторов, ставить ссылки на страницы авторов. Но так как они представлены как uobject, а не upage, соответственно не можно получить ссылки на их страницы.

Как это можно обойти?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Привожу решение на основе кастомного макроса, использующего API.
В /classes/modules/custom.php или /classes/components/custom.php вставить функцию:

```
function getPageByObjectId($iObjectID) {
    $hierarchy = umiHierarchy::getInstance();
    $aPages = $hierarchy->getObjectInstances($iObjectID);
    return isset($aPages[0]) ? ['page' => $hierarchy->getElement($aPages[0])] : '';
}
```

В xslt-шаблоне можно получить ссылку, если она есть такой строчкой:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document(concat('/udata:/custom/getPageByObjectId/',$objectId))/udata/page/@link" />
```